# Wrong `SocketKind` in `SocketActivityTrigger` background task

Tags: c++, windows-10, uwp

During testing of [my project](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer) on a background server, I have encountered the weird situation where every time I triggers a request to my suspended server using `ServerTestingTask`, the `ServerTask` is triggered twice with identical `SocketActivityTriggerDetails` (trigger reason is `SocketActivityTriggerReason::ConnectionAccepted`, the socket information is always `SocketActivityKind::StreamSocketListener`). The problem is that the first one supplies a valid `StreamSocket` in the information and my code handled the request perfectly while the second trigger raises *invalid object* exception (just by accessing `socketInformation->StreamSocket` which is some kind of fatal and kill my server [need to resuming the app UI and click the button to start the server again]. It feels like the first trigger should indicate the socket kind to be `SocketActivityKind::StreamSocket` instead. Is it a known problem or is there some work around?

Comment: Can you get a dump of the crash? This is how I get dumps: https://github.com/kiewic/Projects/tree/master/CrashDumps

Comment: I cannot use the registry but I can get the dump from Visual Studio's `Debug` menu. Here is [the generated dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B374wJUALN6kUGItT2c1NnlpSkE/view?usp=sharing). The exception thrown is: **HRESULT:0x800710D8 The object identifier does not represent a valid object.** right at the line `socket = socketInformation->StreamSocket` in [ServerTask.cpp](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer/blob/master/BackgroundServerTasks/ServerTask.cpp) in the second trigger.

Comment: Do you have a try/catch block? Can you get a dump without the try/catch?

Comment: I have `try/catch` block. With or without them, I cannot use the registry method that you suggested. The crash dump obtained is by via `Debug\Save Dump As ...` from Visual Studio.